# Compare typedef is same type

Tags: c++

I am using C++ (not 11) and using some libraries which have different typedefs for integer data types. Is there any way I can assert that two typedefs are the same type? I've come up with the following solution myself.. is it safe?
Thanks

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeTest
{
    static void Compare(const TypeTest& other) {}
};

typedef unsigned long long UINT64;
typedef unsigned long long UINT_64;
typedef unsigned int UINT_32;

int main()
{
    TypeTest<UINT64>::Compare(TypeTest<UINT64>()); // pass
    TypeTest<UINT64>::Compare(TypeTest<UINT_64>()); // pass
    TypeTest<UINT64>::Compare(TypeTest<UINT_32>()); // fail
}
```

Comment: cppreference has a sample implementation of `std::is_same`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: What's keeping you in the dinosaur era?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In C++11, you could use `std::is_same<T,U>::value`.

Since you don't  have C++11, you could implement this functionality yourself as:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same 
{
    static const bool value = false; 
};

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T,T>  //specialization
{ 
   static const bool value = true; 
};
```

Done!

Likewise you can implement `static_assert`<sup>1</sup> as:

```
template<bool> struct static_assert;
template<> struct static_assert<true> {};  //specialization
```

Now you can use them as:

```
static_assert<is_same<UINT64,UINT64>::value>(); //pass
static_assert<is_same<UINT64,UINT32>::value>(); //fail
```

Or you could wrap this in a macro as:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(x)  { static_assert<x> static_assert_failed; (void) static_assert_failed; }
```

then use as:

```
STATIC_ASSERT(is_same<UINT64,UINT64>::value); //pass
STATIC_ASSERT(is_same<UINT64,UINT32>::value); //pass
```

If you use macro, then you would see the following string in the compiler generated message if the assert fails:

```
static_assert_failed
```

which is helpful. With the other information in the error message, you would be able to figure out why it failed.

Hope that helps.

---

<sup>1. Note that in C++11, `static_assert` is an operator (which operates at compile-time), not a class template. In the above code, `static_assert` is a class template.</sup>

Comment: Hi. I am trying your solution on VS2008, but the line template<bool> static_assert gives errors:
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2998: 'int static_assert' : cannot be a template definition

Comment: @NeilKirk: Oops. I forgot `struct` in the definition of `static_assert`. Fixed it now.

Comment: Say that UINT32 can be defined unsigned int or unsigned long int. Will these compare the same in your code? Thanks.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I didn't get what you're saying. Try and see it yourself, if you face any problem let me know with details.

Comment: On my compiler, these are both 32-bit:
typedef unsigned int UINT_32;
typedef unsigned long int UINT32;

This fails:
static_assert<is_same<UINT32, UINT_32>::value>(); //fail

Thanks.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Those two **are** different types. While the *typedef* looks the same, they refer to different types and are flagged as such by the template. If you want them to test *same* then the question changes completely.

Comment: Ok I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have C++11, use boost.

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_same<T, U>::value);
```

You can write some kind of your assert function, instead of `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.

Comment: While you're already using boost, replace the run-time `assert` with the compile-time `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.

Comment: @MichaelWild, assert is not C assert really, it's some kind of your assert function.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Important thing is, that the OP probably wants the `assert` to pass/fail during compile time, not at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot use boost.

Answer (score 1):

std::type_info might help you.

Comment: @MichaelWild: According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/) page it's not c++ 11 specifc. Am I right ?

Comment: sorry, I confused it with the `<type_traits>` header.