# How to check that two integer typedefs are equivalent?

Tags: c++

I am using some libraries which have their own definitions for integer types. How can I check that two typedefs are for equivalent types? I asked in another question how to check that two typedefs are the same. However, suppose int and long int are both 32-bit on my compiler, and two libraries might use each. I want the check to report that typedef of int and typedef of long int are the same for this compiler (perhaps not for another). Thanks.

This is not the same as the other question. The solution to the other question has (int) and (long int) fail the check, even if both are 32-bit. Now I want them to pass the check please.

I am not using C++11.

Comment: -1 -> You have already asked this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200516/compare-typedef-is-same-type

Comment: NO I DIDN'T. Read the comments of the first answer.

Comment: @Ed It's not the same question. `is_same` will return false on long and long long even if both are 64 bit signed.

Comment: @us2012 those are two different types, regardless of whether they have the same size or not

Comment: @Stephen I am aware of that, but my impression was that the OP's definition of "equivalent" intends those two types to be equivalent. I might be mistaken though?

Comment: @us2012 ahh, right, my mistake

Comment: You should clearly define what you mean by "equivalent".

Comment: Yes. I want to make sure a "INT32" typedef from different libraries, are compatible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution on my own. I only care about integers at the moment, but a more generic solution would be appreciated. Any feedback? Thanks.

```
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long UINT64;
typedef unsigned long long UINT_64;
typedef unsigned int UINT_32;
typedef unsigned long int UINT32;

template<bool> struct static_assert;
template<> struct static_assert<true> {};

#define CHECK_INTEGER_TYPES(T, U) (numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized && numeric_limits<U>::is_specialized && numeric_limits<T>::is_integer && numeric_limits<U>::is_integer && (numeric_limits<T>::is_signed == numeric_limits<U>::is_signed) && (numeric_limits<T>::digits == numeric_limits<U>::digits))

int main()
{
    static_assert<(CHECK_INTEGER_TYPES(UINT64, UINT_64))>(); // pass
    static_assert<CHECK_INTEGER_TYPES(UINT64, UINT64)>(); // pass
    static_assert<CHECK_INTEGER_TYPES(UINT64, UINT_32)>(); // fail
    static_assert<CHECK_INTEGER_TYPES(UINT32, UINT32)>(); // pass
    static_assert<CHECK_INTEGER_TYPES(UINT32, UINT_32)>(); // pass
}
```

Comment: you might want to throw `std::is_convertible(T, U)::value` and `std::is_convertible(U, T)::value` in there

Comment: @StephenLin, he's not using C++11

Comment: @JonathanWakely ahh, missed that part...well, that's good advice for anyone reading other than OP, if they insist on checking something like this