# Validation of Iterator

Tags: c++, assert, c++03, static-assert, iterator-traits

I am working in a C++03 project. And I'm taking an iterator into a template. I need to assert that this iterator references a specific type. **Does C++ provide me a way to do this beyond writing my own struct for validation?**

What I want is the equivalent of this C++14 functionality:

```
static_assert(is_same<iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, int>(), "Not an int iterator");
```

Since it's C++03 I assume that I'll have to use an `assert` and that's fine if it's a runtime only debug check I just need the check to be there.

Comment: @Barry If I am forced to I will use Boost, but I'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare typedef is same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200516/compare-typedef-is-same-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the parameters of the question are:

> A way to do this beyond writing my own struct for validation

And it is assumed:

> I'll have to use an `assert` and that's fine if it's a runtime only debug check

You can use [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) in C++03:

```
assert(typeid(iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type) == typeid(int));
```

Answer (score 3):

C++03 doesn't come with a `static_assert`-type thing, that's a C++11 feature. However, there's [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html). If Boost is not available to you, then this is actually a fairly straightforward thing to write:

```
namespace detail {
    template <bool > struct my_static_assert;
    template <> struct my_static_assert<true> { };

    template <size_t > struct my_tester { };
}

#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(B) \
    typedef ::detail::my_tester< sizeof(::detail::my_static_assert< ((B) == 0 ? false : true) >)> \
        my_static_assert_typedef_ ## __COUNTER__ __attribute__((unused))
```

The idea is that, we take our expression `B`, convert it to a `bool`, and use that in a context where if it's `true`, we'll have a complete type, and if it's `false`, we won't. You cannot take `sizeof()` an incomplete type, so that'll be a compile error.

So if I did:

```
MY_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(int) >= 5);
```

gcc gives me:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:92: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'detail::my_static_assert<false>'
     typedef detail::my_tester< sizeof(detail::my_static_assert< ((B) == 0 ? false : true) >)> \
                                                                                            ^
main.cpp:15:5: note: in expansion of macro 'MY_STATIC_ASSERT'
     MY_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(int) >= 5); 
     ^
```

It's not quite as nice as:

```
main.cpp:15:5: error: static assertion failed: 
     static_assert(sizeof(int) >= 5, ""); 
     ^
```

but then, that's what happens when you don't have a language feature.

---

With that, we can convert:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, int>(),
              "Not an int iterator");
```

To:

```
namespace details {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };

    template <typename T>
    struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value = true; };
}

MY_STATIC_ASSERT(details::is_same<
    std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, int
    >::value); // Not an int iterator
```

`iterator_traits` already existed in C++03, and adding a comment will let the message show up in the compile error.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm OK with just using an `assert`. I'm not trying to rewrite `static_assert` I'm trying to rewrite `is_same` and `iterator_traits`.

Comment: @JonathanMee `iterator_traits` already existed in C++03, and `is_same` is trivial. But updated to provide full solution.

Comment: Ugh, I was scared I'd have to write a struct for validation.

Comment: @JonathanMee If the biggest problem in your code base is writing a 5-line metafunction, then you're doing pretty well.

Comment: Actually I think that my biggest problem is that I'm using C++03.